# Proof using partial fractions

Tags: partial-fractions

I have to prove this formula:

$$\int \! \frac{1}{(x^2+\beta ^2)^{k+1}} \, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2k\beta ^2}\frac{x}{(x^2 +\beta^2)^k}+\frac{2k-1}{2k\beta^2}\int \! \frac{1}{(x^2+\beta ^2)^k} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

I have to use partial fraction decomposition.
I started like this:
$$
\frac{a}{(x^2+\beta ^2)^k}+\frac{b}{x^2+\beta ^2}
$$

Now:
$$
1 = a(x^2+\beta^2) + b(x^2+\beta^2)^k
$$

Now I'm stuck. How do I find $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 0):

Write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(x^2+\beta^2)^{k+1}}&=\frac{1}{\beta^2}\frac{(x^2+\beta^2)-x^2}{(x^2+\beta^2)^{k+1}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\beta^2}\left(\frac{1}{(x^2+\beta^2)^{k}}- \frac{x^2}{(x^2+\beta^2)^{k+1}}\right)
\end{align}$$

Now, integrate both sides and use integration by parts on the last term.  Combine terms of like powers and you will have it.

---

NOTE:  Integration by parts

$$-\int \frac{x^2}{(x^2+\beta^2)^{k+1}} dx = \frac{1}{2k}\frac{x}{(x^2+\beta^2)^k}-\frac{1}{2k}\int \frac{1}{(x^2+\beta^2)^{k+1}}dx$$

Comment: But how does that prove the formula?

Comment: You have to combine terms.  Shall I add to the post